# PHP MySQL database class not working with insertion

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I've been using this class:

```
<?
class DbConnector {

var $theQuery;
var $link;

function DbConnector() {

    $host = 'localhost';
    $db = 'my_db';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = 'password';

    // connect to the db
    $this->link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    mysql_select_db($db);
    register_shutdown_function(array(&$this, 'close'));
}

function find($query) {
    $ret = mysql_query($query, $this->link);
    if (mysql_num_rows($ret) == 0)
        return array();
    $retArray = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($ret))
        $retArray[] = $row;

    return $retArray;
}

function insert($query) {
    $ret = mysql_query($query, $this->link);

    if (mysql_affected_rows() < 1)
        return false;
    return true;
}

function query($query) {
    $this->theQuery = $query;
    return mysql_query($query, $this->link);
}

// get some results
function fetchArray($result) {

    return mysql_fetch_array($result);
}

function close() {
    mysql_close($this->link);
}

function exists($query) {
    $ret = mysql_query($query, $this->link);
    if (mysql_num_rows($ret) == 0)
        return false;
}

function last_id($query) {
    return mysql_insert_id($query);
}

}

?>
```

Which I'm using for a lot of queries and it's working fine, although I'm trying to insert using this query:

```
    global $db;
        $query = $db->insert("INSERT INTO  `submissions` (
         `id` ,
        `quote` ,
        `filename` ,
        `date_added` ,
        `uploaded_ip`
        )
    VALUES (
    NULL ,  '{$quote}',  '{$filename}',  NOW(),  '{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}')
    ");
```

And it's giving me this error:

```
Not Found

 The requested URL /horh_new/id/<br /><b>Fatal error</b>: Call to a member function        insert() on a non-object in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/horh_new/addit.php</b> on line <b>52</b><br /> was not found on this server.
```

Although when I don't use that class above, and use this instead:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
 if (!$con) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

 mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO  `submissions` (
         `id` ,
        `quote` ,
        `filename` ,
        `date_added` ,
        `uploaded_ip`
        )
    VALUES (
    NULL ,  '{$quote}',  '{$filename}',  NOW(),  '{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}')
    ");

 echo mysql_insert_id();

 mysql_close($con);
```

It works fine. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my class? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Well from that error I'd say that $db isnt what you're expecting. Dump it out and what do you see?

Comment: Your $db variable hasn't been instantiated where you get that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do like

```
global $db;
$db = new DbConnector();
```

Or the better way to use this is

add a static function of class DbConnector, which will create only single instance throughout a request

```
public static function getInstance(){
   static $instance = null;
   if($instance === null){
      $instance = new DbConnector();
   }

   return $instance;    
}
```

And use this class as

```
$db = DbConnector::getInstance();
$db->insert($query);
```

Comment: so `$db = DbConnector::getInstance();` basically just checks to see if an instance has been created or not yet? Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: this will create the new instance if it has not been created, other wise it will return old instance. And more thing in such type of situations __constructor should not be public.

Answer (score 2):

you need to instantiate the object before using it

```
$db = new DbConnetor();
```

now you can do an insert

although i suggest adding a __construct method to connect to the database first

```
class DbConnector {

  public function __construct() {
     // connect to db here

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure $db contains an instance of your class? Maybe just do a  var_dump()  of $db just before your call to $db->insert() and see if it's set.